# Programmatically Zooming in D3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization

Using the JavaScript visualisation library D3, how do you programmatically set the zoom behaviour so that it jumps to somewhere else and then as you scroll or zoom it does not just revert back to the original position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it jumps is that within the code for the zoom behaviour, D3 copies the scale and uses that to make calculations for scrolling and zooming. To fix it you need to force the internal copy to go to the position that you want.

This can be done by calling .x or .y on the zoom object. For example, if you had an xScale that you change then pass the xScale back into the .x of the zoom object to set the internal copy to that xScale.

Comment: Could you post an example of the code? This would help me in my case! Thank you